# Question about IRR and early prepayment

Tags: present-value

Suppose I look at a 36 month loan for \$10,000 at 20%. Thus my payment per month is \$166.67. Thus my IRR should be 20% (on an annualized basis).

Now let's suppose I prepay my loan early at the end of 24 months. Doing the calculation, I still get the same IRR of 20%. Can someone confirm that this is in fact the case?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: This should migrate to mathematics or economics.

Comment: You need to provide more information. When exactly are you calculating IRR? If principal is returned early, future interest payments may not be paid on that part of the principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the IRR is the same regardless of the prepayment date.  The only thing that varies is the life of the loan.